# Ruby on Rails で定期実行するファイルの置き場所はどこにしますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. A というサイトの更新情報を RSS から定期的に取得したい
2. CakePHP の時は、 `app/Console/Command/CrawlShell.php` としていた
3. Ruby on Rails の場合はどこにファイルを作成したらいいでしょうか？

現状は `app/controller/crawl.rb` というファイルを作成して crontab などで定期実行しようと思っていますが、このやり方はあっていますか？

それとも、定期実行するファイルの置き場所の規約などはありますか？

ご回答おまちしております。

Answer (score 1):

規則については存じあげないので個人的意見ですが、`lib/tasks`にタスクとして書くことが多いです。

`scripts/runner` に書いても良いのですが、

- rails をロードしないタスクが書ける、とか
- namespace で分類できる、とか

があるので、タスクにしています。